# Airflow: SQL to GCS error with NULL datetime fields

Tags: airflow

I'm using the **MsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator** operator to extract data from my MSSQL server DB, and I noticed that if I query tables that have **datetime** fields using a **SELECT * FROM [table_name**] my task will fail with a

```
ERROR - Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

The only round this has been to specify the fields I want and even in that case if there's a datetime field that's **NULL** I get the same error. Any clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current operator. There is a [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11540) pending to be approved that fix that.

However you don't need to wait for the release to address the issue.
As a temporary workaround you can copy the code from the PR into your environment creating a custom operator

```
TempMsSqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
```

Once the fix is released you can remove the custom operator and import the fixed operator from the latest version of [provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/) (for Airflow >= 2.0.0) or [backport-provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/) (for Airflow < 2.0.0)

Comment: I wrote the custom operator and fixed the datetime issue but I noticed that float values in the JSON payload can't be processed because the schema has defined them as INTEGER